# Windows auto release mutex when process crash

Tags: windows, winapi, crash, multiprocessing, abandonedmutexexception

I use global mutex in multi-process in windows, however, the mutex won't be released when the owner process crashes, and then another process calls `WaitForSingleObject`, it returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`, how should I do to let this mutex relase, or do some other actions when returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`?

Comment: you take ownership of the mutex object after `WaitForSingleObject` return `WAIT_ABANDONED`. you not need any special actions in this case.

Comment: and you wrong understand documentation. the mutex object of course **released**. otherwise you simply not got ownership for it. from doc *mutex object that was not released by the thread that owned the mutex object **before** the owning thread terminated*. so mutex is released **after** thread terminate by system itself. this is mean `WAIT_ABANDONED`

Comment: Yes, however `WAIT_ABANDONED` indicates that since the mutex was not released gracefully by the owning thread, any shared resources being protected by the mutex are in an unknown and potentially unstable state and should not be trusted anymore, unless you have a way of recovering the data and resetting it to a known and stable state.

Comment: See [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253) on MSDN: "*If the thread that owns a mutex exits without releasing the mutex, **the mutex is automatically released on the thread's behalf**.
But if this happens, you're in big trouble.
[WAIT_ABANDONED is typically treated] as a successful wait, because **it does mean that the object was obtained**, but it also tells you that the previous owner left the mutex abandoned and that the system had to release it on the owner's behalf.*"